# How to get printf to treat the variables passed from bc script differently?

Tags: bash, bc

I'm writing a program for CodeWars that requires me to return 2 specific variables with a space between them.

The following is the script that I am trying to execute

```
!/bin/bash

nbMonths()
{
    printf "%.0f\n" $(
    bc <<< "
      scale=5
      osum=$1
      nsum=$2
      sav=0
      lper=($4 / 100)
      cmon=0

      diff = osum + sav - nsum

      while( diff < 0 ) {
         osum -= ( osum * lper )
         nsum -= ( nsum * lper )
         sav += $3
         cmon += 1
      
         scale=0
         if( (cmon%2) == 1) {
           scale=5
           lper += 0.005
         }
    
         scale=5
         diff = osum + sav - nsum
      } 

      print cmon, diff
    ")
}

nbMonths $1 $2 $3 $4
```

For the following input to the bash script

> bash nameOfProg.sh 2000 8000 1000 1.5

The result it shows is

> 6766

While I would like it to display it as

> 6 766

There are 2 questions I have regarding this,

1. Is there a way to make printf to print in the above format?
2. I've noticed that `print cmon, \", \", diff` results in

   > 6, 766

   Are there are escape sequences(like `\",\"`) that I could use? If so, where could I find it since there isn't a man page for `print`.

Please note that the reason I've used `%0.f` in the `printf` statement is that I need the last value (from diff) to be rounded off.

Comment: looks to me, from your own evidence, that `print cmon, \" \", diff` would put a space there.  I think that's what you want?  your version was close, you just put a comma between the (escaped) quotes

Comment: Oh man! That worked. I just did not understand what \", \" was. I noticed its use in different program and just used it here. Thank you so very much. Could you help me with what exactly is \" \"? Also, is there a man page for print? Thank you in advance

Comment: Include a [mre].

Comment: `print` is a command within `bc`, and the fact that `\"` does something is due to shell quoting rules and not anything to do with `bc`. And, to @oguzismail's point, you can replace the whole `bc` command with a one-liner that prints two numbers to show the problem.

Comment: @tankris see my answer for how a minimal example of this might have been provided.  By pulling most of the logic out of the function for the purposes of this question, it keeps the conversation focused and makes it easy for folks to test out their recommendations without thinking too much about irrelevant stuff.  unfortunately coming up with minimal reproducible examples is sometimes a tricky change of perspective , especially for newer programmers, but it's a great exercise

Answer (score 0):

you can print a space in a `bc` `print` command by enquoting the space in double strings.

Since your `bc` input is already enquoted, you'll need to *escape* the quotes with backslashes so it doesn't end the here-string (data following `<<<`).

Here's a simple example:

```
$  bc <<<"print 1, \" \", 3, \" \", 4"; echo
1 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

> While I would like it to display it as

Then:

1. Remove `printf`
2. Read [bc documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC15) and note that strings start and end with double quotes.
3. Learn about shell quoting. If you are inside `"` quotes, then to pass `"` you have to escape it.

   ```
   $ cat <<<"inside double quotes: literal quote: \" "
   inside double quotes: literal quote: "
   ```
4. Print the space between numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash
bc <<<"
  scale=5
  osum=$1
  nsum=$2
  sav=0
  lper=($4 / 100)
  cmon=0

  diff = osum + sav - nsum

  while( diff < 0 ) {
     osum -= ( osum * lper )
     nsum -= ( nsum * lper )
     sav += $3
     cmon += 1
  
     scale=0
     if( (cmon%2) == 1) {
       scale=5
       lper += 0.005
     }

     scale=5
     diff = osum + sav - nsum
  } 

   print cmon, \" \", diff
"
```

Comment: If you are writing a 100% `bc` script program, then use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env -S bc -l` and have the whole script handled by `bc`